# Why comparing 2 strings doesn't give desired result?

Tags: c++, string, comparison, strcmp

Below is the code I've come up with and in all honesty tonight is my first attempt at coding at all.  However I cannot seem to get my `if` statement to work properly.  It just simply jumps to else even if I type Westley or westley or (space)Westley.

I want the program to be able to accept any of my team members names however I figured I get my name working and then I could add the rest of them later.  Any thoughts or help would be wonderful.  Also as a side note I was going to try and loop it if it went to the else back up to the begining any thoughts on that as well?  Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char Westley[] = "Westley";
  char Alex[] = "Alex";
  char Andrea[] = "Andrea";
  char Bee[] = "Bee";
  char Gia[] = "Gia";
  char KaYeng[] = "Ka Yeng";
  char Chi[] = "Chi";
  char Corinne[] = "Corinne";
  char Joyce[] = "Joyce";
  char Parish[] = "Parish";
  char membername [80];
  cout << "Please Enter a Beta Team Members Name.\n";
  cin >> membername;
  if (membername == Westley)
  {   cout << "BETA TEAM ROSTER!!\n";
      cout << "Westley.\n";
      cout << "Alex.\n";
      cout << "Andrea.\n";
      cout << "Bee.\n";
      cout << "Gia.\n";
      cout << "Ka Yeng.\n";
      cout << "Chi.\n";
      cout << "Corinne.\n";
      cout << "Joyce.\n";
      cout << "Parish.\n";
  }
  else
      cout << "Not a Valid Beta Team Members Name!\n" << "Please Enter a Beta Team Members Name"<< endl;
cin >> membername;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first attempt at coding and you chose C++?  Gutsy.

Comment: You might find it instructive to read this short PDF by Bjarne Stroustrup which differentiates the "C way" of writing safe/correct IO vs the "C++ way": http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are coding with C++ you should use `std::string` instead of `char []`. It has the convenience that you can compare two strings (alas with `char []` you have to call functions like `strcmp` or the like).

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // <-- important
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string Westley("Westley");
    ...

    if(membername == Westley) // now works!
    {
        ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `char[]`; use `std::string` for this sort of thing as that knows how to do comparisons in a helpful way (comparisons between char arrays test if they are the same array, not if the contents is identical).

Answer (score 4):

You can not use "==" operator. Try to find out more about

> strcmp

```
if (strcmp(membername, "Westley") == 0)
   ...
```

Answer (score 4):

this is c++ and you are using a char array not a string you need to use `strcmp` for string comparison

you can do this like

```
if(strcmp(membarname, Westley))
```

or if possible you can use `std::string` instead of `char[]` to store a string then you can use `==` operator

you can use the `std::string` as follows

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string Westley = "Westley";

    ....

    string membername;
    cout << "Please Enter a Beta Team Members Name.\n";
    cin >> membername;
    if (membername == Westley){

        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of character array `char[]`; use `std::string` and you will get the desired result.

```
if (membername == Westley)
```

Because, for `char[]` data, above comparison results in *address comparison* and not the *content comparison*.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is arrays you are working with you need to use strmcp instead e.g.

```
if (!strcmp(membername, Westley) ...
```

since you are working in C++ use instead string:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string Westley = "Westley";
```

...
then you can do

```
if (membername == Westley) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The == operator you are using compares the addresses of the strings. To compare two C Strings use the `strcmp` function from `<cstring>` (`string.h`). In C++ you should use the `std::string` class template, which can be intuitively compared using the == operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (membername == Westley)
```

only compare two pointers' value.